# How Side by Side CLR in a single window process handles GC and multiple AppDomain?

Tags: .net, clr

I am trying to understand when multiple CLR's loaded into single window process.

- Does each AppDomain will be mapped to a specific CLR.  Then how thread moving from one AppDomain to other understands different runtime ?
- There will be one GC for a window process?  Or separate GC for each CLR loaded into the process ?

Help me to understand. Thanks.

Comment: Capture a dump of Office when it loads multiple CLRs then you can easily observe the case. Each CLR manages its own managed heaps, so dedicate GC thread(s) of that CLR can free the objects correctly. Managed threads are mapped to native threads, so they are isolated logically if coming from different CLRs. The same should apply to AppDomain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CLRs loaded into a process have no knowledge of each other. As far as each run-time is concerned, the others are just native code using their own unmanaged memory. This means that an object cannot be passed from run-time to another, instead it must go through the same pinning/marshaling requirements for inter-operating with native code.

If a method in CLRv2 called a method in CLRv4, they would both see the same native thread but have their own 'managed thread' view of it. CLRv2 would simply think it's calling a native method while CLRv4 would think it's being called from native code.

Comment: Thanks,  So What I understand is that I run a Program A based on CLR v4.  Program A creates a AppDomain which loads a Assembly B based on CLR v2.  Is I understood right ?

Comment: @Vytheese I gave an example, Microsoft Office above, which is a native app and can load both .NET 2 and 4 CLRs side by side. That's almost the only Microsoft product that seriously uses this runtime feature. IIS and MMC simply refuse to do so. If your program A is a .NET 4 app, not a native one, it would be quite difficult to simulate Office to load .NET 2 CLR side by side without lots of PInvoke. By default the .NET 2 assembly B will be loaded by CLR 4 in that case.

Comment: @Vytheese, the AppDomain is a component of the run-time. When the CLRv4 is told to create a new AppDomain, it will be created within CLRv4. You can't tell the CLR to create a new AppDomain in a different CLR because they just don't know about each other. What you can do however, is to [use the COM hosting API to create a new run-time and call a method within it](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppHostCLR-e6581ee0).

Comment: @LexLi, I believe Visual Studio also did it, so that the process could switch to .NET 4 without breaking plugins written for CLRv2.

Comment: @BrianReichle, The link made lot of sense.  Thanks.